# missing Database error in java with sqlite

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite

```
 @Override
public void saveOrder(OrderModel order) {
    try {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        if (loadOrder(order.orderID) == null) {           // this is a new product!
            stmt.execute("INSERT INTO Order (OrderID, OrderDate, Customer, TotalCost, TotalTax) VALUES ("
                    +  order.orderID + ","
                    + '\'' + order.orderDate+ '\'' + ","
                    + order.customer + ","
                    + order.totalCost + ","
                    + order.totalTax+ ")"
            );
        }
```

I am trying to get information to save to my Order table in my database but it keeps giving me this error. I am not seeing what I did wrong. It says the problem is the  stmt.execute line but I can't figure out what to change.
[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "Order": syntax error)

Comment: How did you create the database? Where is the code that establishes the connection? Is the filename given correct?  Please update your question and include all the relevant code.

Comment: `Order` is a reserved word in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your execute statement.

**INSERT** (as well as **UPDATE** and **DELETE**) statements should use `executeUpdate()`.